# Access 'main' module functions and vars from imported module

Tags: python

main.py

```
import try_modules
cats = 2
try_modules.printCats()
```

try_modules.py

```
def printCats():
    global cats
    print cats
```

This throw an error. What's the right way to use 'pseudo-global' vars from main module into imported modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that requirement, this is generally a bad design, but you can do:

```
 import try_modules
 try_modules.cats = 2
 try_modules.printCats()
```

If you have several module needing one variable put it in a module holding the variable (again I don't think this should be used, you should rather pass an object around holding the variable):

`module_a.py`

```
import global_vars

global_vars.a = 23
```

`module_b.py`

```
import global_vars

print global_vars.a
```

`global_vars.py`

```
a = 37
```

and `main.py`

```
import module_a
import module_b
```

will print `23`, and the variable `a` is shared across all the modules.

Comment: I over simplified the example code, but I've 10 imported modules, every one needing to access cats variable. Suggest a good design, please

Comment: Easy then, create a module that handles all your shared variables and access them from the other modules.

Comment: @realtebo Pass it as a parameter to the `printCats` functions `printCats(cats)`. If they are constants then you can do what Ic2817 suggested, but if they are mutable, it's a really bad design to have mutable global variables.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: agreed

Comment: Thanks, I'm already starting global redesign, using a module with also getter and setters for app wide variables

Answer (score 0):

Your main.py doesn't know what module the variable cats belongs to. Use

```
try_modules.cats = 2
```

or fix your import to read

```
from try_modules import cats
```